# Strategy for queuing up functincalls asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

My JSF app does the following:

1. User inputs rows of data into a input ares.
2. User hit submit, button action is wired up to call remote REST services (1 call per row data)
3. Result of each REST call persisted into DB.

Problem is this operation is synchronous and the user does not have control of the UI until the calls are finished.

Comment: More detail on "button action is wired up to call remote REST".

Comment: I don't think this is really anything to do with the 'REST' side of things... you simple need to look up how to do asynchronous things on the client with JSF pages.